# How to get the Fourier series coefficients back after applying fft on a set of data point?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Assume that I have a series of points and I applied the fft.fft to the data, how can I recognize the coefficients of the original Fourier series, i know that the a_0 is directly can be extracted from the maximum value of fft.fft, but what about a_n and b_n I know also that they may appear on the spectrum but is there a method here?
X = np.array([917, 918, 919, 918, 917, 916, 915, 913, 912, 910, 906, 903, 901, 899, 897, 896, 896, 896, 896, 896, 896, 897, 898, 900, 903, 905, 908, 911, 914, 916, 919, 919, 918, 918, 917, 916, 914, 913, 911, 913, 905, 901, 899, 898])
f = np.fft.fft(X)
but if we plot x with time we find it is periodic one that can be written in terms of Fourier Series:
f(x) = a_0/2 + Sigma(a_n*np.cos(2*n*np.pi/L)+b_n*np.sin(2*n*np.pi/L))
How can I get back the a_0, a_n, and b_n?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want to do? The numpy fft documentation is quite detailed.

Comment: x=[1215, 1219, 1221, 1213, 1215, 1216, 1217] this is a series that we can apply np.fft.ff(x) right? now this is a representation of fourier series that is compound of a_0+ Sigma(a_n*cos(2n*pi/L)+b_n*sin(2n*pi/L)) right? how can I get back a_0, a_n, and b_n back from this computation?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so you have 7 input elements, starting with 1215+0i, 1219+0i and so on (complex values but in your case they happen to be purely real). It's normal to pad to a power of 2, but OK. The result will start with the DC coefficient a_0 (also complex but the imaginary component will be 0), and then the next element of the result will be the lowest non-DC frequency (in your notation a_1 + b_1*i) and so on.
From the doc at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.fft.html#module-numpy.fft:

> The values in the result follow so-called “standard” order: If A =
>   fft(a, n), then A[0] contains the zero-frequency term (the sum of the
>   signal), which is always purely real for real inputs. Then A[1:n/2]
>   contains the positive-frequency terms, and A[n/2+1:] contains the
>   negative-frequency terms, in order of decreasingly negative frequency.
>   For an even number of input points, A[n/2] represents both positive
>   and negative Nyquist frequency, and is also purely real for real
>   input. For an odd number of input points, A[(n-1)/2] contains the
>   largest positive frequency, while A[(n+1)/2] contains the largest
>   negative frequency.

Now since your input array is all reals, you might look into `np.fft.rfft` which will be faster. The result will be symmetric (because of real input), so it'll contain only half the actual coefficients -- the other half can be derived from the given result. See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.fft.html#module-numpy.fft for more.